# How can I get data from the acf.maps field?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I tried to make a simple fetch from the Wordpress API. In this case from ACF Fields.

With the code:

I get a response. But if I try
to add

${post.acf.address}

there are no data. But why, anyone who can help me?

Here is the code:

```
function getPosts() {
  fetch(
    "https://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/tourplan?per_page=100"
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let output = '<h2 class="mb-4">Posts</h2>';
      data.forEach(function(post) {
        output += `
                  <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                    <h2>${post.acf.location}</h3>
                    <h3>${post.acf.programmname}</h3>
                    <p>${post.acf.datum}</p>
                    <p>${post.acf.beginn}</p>
                  </div>
                `;
        console.log(data);
      });
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    });
}
```

This is the json response if you call the fetch url in a browser.

```
[
    {
        "id": 5692,
        "date": "2019-05-08T14:41:15",
        "date_gmt": "2019-05-08T12:41:15",
        "guid": {
            "rendered": "https://localhost/?post_type=tourplan&#038;p=5692"
        },
        "modified": "2019-05-08T14:41:15",
        "modified_gmt": "2019-05-08T12:41:15",
        "slug": "münchen",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "tourplan",
        "link": "https://localhost/Tourplan/münchen/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "München"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "",
            "protected": false
        },
        "template": "",
        "authorName": "wtced",
        "acf": {
            "plz": "81825",
            "location": "Wirtshaus",
            "programmname": "\"Programmname\"",
            "datum": "20190913",
            "einlass": "18:00",
            "beginn": "20:00",
            "ticketlink": "https://localhost/hxanh/",
            "ausverkauft": false,
            "vvk": "Veranstalter: Testverein e.V.",
            "zusatzfeld": "",
            "maps": {
                "address": "Feldstraße 35, 81825 München, Deutschland",
                "lat": "48.386076050384",
                "lng": "11.348405060504"
            }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `address` property is inside the `maps` property `${post.acf.maps.address}`

Not every post object have maps property so you will need to check if that field exists

```
data.forEach(function({ acf }) {
  output += `
    <div class="card card-body mb-3">
      <h2>${acf.location}</h3>
      <h3>${acf.programmname}</h3>
      <p>Open Doors: ${acf.einlass}</p>
      <p>Start at: ${acf.beginn}</p>
      <p>${acf.maps && acf.maps.address ? acf.maps.address : 'No address found'}</p>
    </div>
  `;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I get into inside of this property? <p>${post.acf.maps.address}</p> doesn't work.

Comment: yes it does but when you fetch from a real url it doesn't work.
https://jsfiddle.net/fk30t1e2/1/

Comment: @hobboh not every post has `maps` property so you will need to check if it exist, I've updated my answer to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, the code was okay. The reason for doesn't work were too many results.